# « C'est le monde renversé/à l'envers » : origine et raison de la dualité, fréquence relative ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, origine-ou-raison, synonymes

> *C'est le monde [renversé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/renvers%C3%A9), à l'[envers](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envers)*, c'est le contraire de ce qui se fait ordinairement ou de ce qui devrait se faire.
>
> [ Larousse en ligne, [*monde*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/monde/52177/locution?q=monde#182024) ]

Un [*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monde%20renvers%C3%A9%2Cmonde%20%C3%A0%20l%27envers&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmonde%20renvers%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmonde%20%C3%A0%20l%20%27%20envers%3B%2Cc0) montrerait que l'emploi de « monde à l'envers » est plus fréquent et qu'il a augmenté plus rapidement que l'emploi de « monde renversé » depuis 1960, pour connaître ensuite un déclin, peut-être au profit de l'autre, tout en restant l'emploi le plus fréquent (en 2009).

---

- L'un ou l'autre emploi est-il plus fréquent à un endroit ou à un
  autre de la francophonie aujourd'hui ou sont-ils tous les deux aussi usuels ?
- Comment expliquer l'augmentation le cas échéant de l'emploi de «
  monde à l'envers » au *ngram* etc. ?
- Les deux emplois ont-ils toujours été historiquement en concurrence et originent-ils de la même époque ; pourquoi l'expression avec *c'est* ne s'est pas figée avec l'un ou l'autre, qu'est-ce que reflète cette dualité et pourquoi la synonymie semble l'emporter sur le figement ici ?

Comment: J'ai souvent entendu "le monde à l'envers", mais jamais ou presque "le monde renversé". J'ai toujours vécu en France.

Comment: @Distic Même constat pour le Québec, quoique le monde renversé se rencontre parfois à l'écrit ou dans certains types de discussion, lorsque le renversement du monde est utilisé de manière systématique pour créer un effet artistique ou confronter philosophiquement un état reçu des faits (comme par exemple dans ce [roman japonais](https://www.lesbelleslettres.com/livre/2286-si-on-les-echangeait-le-genji-travesti)).

Answer (score 3):

Malgré une signification identique, ces deux expressions ne sont pas vraiment en compétition, leur usage et registre étant le plus souvent distinct.

**Le monde renversé** est la transcription en français du latin *mundus inversus*. C'est un thème que l'on rencontre essentiellement dans des œuvres artistiques, philosophiques, tableaux etc.

**C'est le monde à l'envers** est une expression toute faite du français courant. C'est quasiment la seule que l'on entend en français parlé aujourd'hui et elle décrit, comme la précédente, une situation, une organisation, un agencement à l'opposé d'ordre naturel ou établi.

Comment: *Le monde renversé* n'est-il vraiment qu'un thème? Je n'utilise pas habituellement cette expression et ne la rencontre en effet que dans la littérature imprimée, mais l'exemple du TLFi semble indiquer qu'il pourrait aussi s'agir d'une expression synonyme du *monde à l'envers*: *«Donner la préférence à votre protégée, ce serait le monde renversé!»*

Comment: @Feelew Cette forme est possible mais ce n'est pas une locution utilisée dans le français parlé aujourd'hui. L'utiliser serait très littéraire et je pense, comme Distic, ne jamais l'avoir entendue.

Comment: J'ai déjà vu (chez Sartre) "un monde à l'envers" dans le sens que vous donnez à "monde renversé" donc ce n'est peut être pas si distinct que ça.

Comment: @Distic ***Le** monde à l'envers* est une locution contrairement à ***un** monde à l'envers*.

Comment: @Distic et j'ai indiqué deux fois dans ma réponse que le sens est identique.